# Customizing enumerations

Tags: enumerate, enumitem

Not a long time ago when customizing my enumerations, I came across the **enumitem** package, which helped me to do it more quickly.

But I'm lost to find the way to do the following thing.
[image: Example]

I want those begginings of items to be shifted by `\parindent`, like the rest of the text inside those items. but when I try to do that I see that they are shifted. but with the whole text after them.

Here is the code for that example.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist{parsep=0pt,leftmargin=0cm, labelindent=\parindent, listparindent=\parindent,labelwidth=\itemindent,labelsep=0cm,align=left}
\begin{document}
...
\section{Способы описания систем}

Каждая система имеет функциональное, морфологическое и информационное описание.

\begin{enumerate}
\item \textbf{Функциональное описание}

Функциональное описание системы -- это описание системы как совокупности действий, необходимых для достижения определенной цели.

Каждый элемент в системе имеет определённое предназначение, то есть выполняет определенную функцию. Функциональные свойства элементов можно разделить на
...
\end{document}
```

Is there any solution? Or shall I write those without enumerations, keeping the items in mind?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forgot `itemindent=!`. Add this option to your `\setlist` and you will achieve what you want.

MWE

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist{
  parsep=0pt,
  leftmargin=0cm,
  itemindent=!,
  labelindent=\parindent,
  listparindent=\parindent,
  labelwidth=\itemindent,
  labelsep=0cm,
  align=left
  }

\begin{document}

\section{Способы описания систем}

Каждая система имеет функциональное, морфологическое и информационное описание.

\begin{enumerate}
\item \textbf{Функциональное описание}

Функциональное описание системы -- это описание системы как совокупности действий, необходимых для достижения определенной цели.

Каждый элемент в системе имеет определённое предназначение, то есть выполняет определенную функцию. Функциональные свойства элементов можно разделить на
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]